# How to create an animation that plays on layout touch in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to create an animation that plays when clicking on a RelativeLayout, pushing back all the elements that it contains. I have been searching for a while and I have found the function setOnTouchListener() which seems to be the only listener that does what I want.

This is the LinearLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/list_item">
```

Now I am using this code:

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //v.performClick();
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS) {
            itemView.startAnimation(Animations.back);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE) {
            // ...
        } else return false;
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is the animation, if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

The problem is that after adding `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS` the animation is not played anymore, while without it the animaton plays. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS)'s documentation:

> This action is not a touch event so it is delivered to View#onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent) rather than View#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent).

Same is valid for the [ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE) event. These events are probably used for physical button events.

You must use the [ACTION_DOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_DOWN) for press event and [ACTION_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_UP) for release event instead, for touch events.

So modify your code as following:

```java
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    itemView.startAnimation(Animations.back);
} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    // ...
} else return false;
```